# error mysql no deja agregar usuario

Tags: sql

quiero agregar  el usuario admin a esta tabla me da este error

```
create table user(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    lastname varchar(50) not null,
    username varchar(50),
    email varchar(255) not null,
    password varchar(60) not null,
    image varchar(255),
    is_active boolean not null default 1,
    kind_id int not null,
    foreign key(kind_id) references kind(id),
    created_at datetime not null
);
```

Query

```
insert into user(name,username,password,is_active,kind_id,created_at) 
value ("Admin","admin",sha1(md5("admin")),1,1,NOW());
```

error que muestra

Error
consulta SQL: Copiar

> insert into user(name,username,password,is_active,kind_id,created_at) value ("Admin","admin",sha1(md5("admin")),1,1,NOW());
> MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1364 - Field 'lastname' doesn't have a default value

En local con XAMPP se agrega muy bien pero en el servidor es donde no me deja me da error

Comment: Gracias Buen hombre, saludos! solucionado

Answer (score 0):

Hola quizas es porque te hace falta los campos de lastname, image y el email, intenta con esta query:

```
INSERT INTO user (name, lastname, username, email, password, image, 
is_active, kind_id, created_at) 
VALUE ("Admin", "Super", "admin", "admin@gmail.com", "admin",  "imagen#1", 1, 1, NOW());
```